# declaring gridview selectcommand

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview

When the page loads, the GridView (located in an update panel) should be loaded with my first SQL `SELECT` statement.

On the button click, the same GridView will be loaded with new data.

What am i doing wrong? On startup, the GridView doesn't appear.

```
Public cmd As New SqlCommand()
    Public percentp As New SqlCommand()
    Public da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Public conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=TEST-TEST-TEST01;Initial Catalog=TEST;Integrated Security=True")

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    cmd.Connection = conn
    conn.Open()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from test1"
    da.Fill(ds)
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Mapped)
    conn.Close()        
End Sub   

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    cmd.Connection = conn
    conn.Open()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from test"
    da.Fill(ds)
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Mapped)
    conn.Close()        
    TextBox1.Text="aaaaaaaaaaa"
End Sub
End Class
```

I tried
   GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
   GridView1.DataBind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
GridView1.DataBind() // this is needed to bind the datasource to GridView
```

Comment: I did   
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        GridView1.DataBind 
and it didn't work

Comment: now it loads the first table, but when i click the button to update it to the next query it keeps it as the same

Comment: yea you need to do the same with the other event... on your Button1_Click

Comment: of course because you're doing the same thing again (SELECT * FROM test), you need to do different thing to see that your GridView changes.

Comment: no those aren't the actual queries i just posted those on the site the queries are different, is there a way to clear the data grid, in the beginning of the button click

Comment: If you set a new DataSource then the old one will be ignored. The problem might be your query as well, so you might wanna check that using SSMS

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `GridView1.DataBind();` after setting the data source.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to include the GridView1.Databind() command after you retrieve your data from the database. You typically set your data source after you retrieve your data, so your Page_Load method would work better like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    cmd.Connection = conn
    conn.Open()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from test1"
    da.Fill(ds)
    conn.Close()        
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    GridView1.DataBind()        
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you,  it now loads the first table, but when i click the button to update it to the next query it keeps it as the same

Comment: I think you have your answers above, but everytime the page posts back for an update, you will need to call the databinding method again. ASP.Net is stateless, so it doesn't automatically track changes to the datasource, and will cache the previous data in the ViewState to prevent it having to bind again.